# не прогружается карта в android studio

Tags: android-studio

очень нуждаюсь в вашей помощи...

столкнулся с такой проблемой.

использовал Android Studio (а в нем эмулятор андройда) в котором подменивал геолокацию

все было отлично на протяжении года. но 2 дня назад перестала прогружаться карта и поиск адресов (теперь вместо карты я вижу просто белый экран)... может кто нибудь знает в чем дело и как это можно исправить??
буду очень вам признателен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: готов заплатить за помощь